# Is ANTS Performance Profile able to track AJAX calls in an web application?

Tags: ajax, red-gate-ants

I have a web application where I use simple AJAX calls using jQuery in my pages. I just want to know whether ANTS Performance Profiler will track the AJAX calls and show the results for AJAX calls also just a normal method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using ANTS Performance Profiler Pro 7.3+ and a profiling mode other than Sampling then you will see two nodes in the call-tree for an AJAX call. One node will be a HTTP node for the actual request, the second node will be the method that is run on a separate thread that served up the data to the client. 
If you are also using MS SQL or Oracle you will also see those nodes in the call-tree and the Database view.